# Appropriate image size for iPad Retina & iPad Non-Retina display

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, splash-screen

I am developing a Universal Apps. The images are displaying perfectly in iPhone. But their quality is getting decreased in iPad Non-Retina display.
It seems like iPad getting the 1x image every where in the Apps.
I never develope universal apps before, and didn't find any perfect resource out there describing image size for iPad Retina and Non-Retina display. So it would be really appreciable if someone give me any suggestion or resource about the image naming convention and their size for iPad Retina and Non-Retina display.

Example:
For iPhone 4, 5, 6, 6+

image > 44px x 44px
image@2x > 88px x 88px
image@3x > 132px x 132px

What for iPad Non-Retina & Retina display?
Is it? Then what will be the size for 44px x 44px < 1x image?

image~ipad.png (Non-Retina)
image@2x~ipad.png (Retina)

Comment: The idea behind universal is that is.....universal. This means it will scale based on screen size.

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on your imageview's size. If you are using imageview with same size in iphone and ipad then your same image set should work.

for example if your imageview's size on iphone is 44x44 and same on ipad also then your 1x,2x and 3x should be same for both iphone and ipad as 44x44,88x88, and 132x132 respactively.

but now, you are using larger imageview on iPad says 60x60 then your ipad should required 1x,2x,3x of size 60x60,120x120,180x180 respactively.

You can set universal image set or for iphone and ipad only from assets. you can change it from attribute inspector from assets.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, My `imageView` size is fixed in every device, including iPad. And it's 44 by 44. But the image is not clearly showing in iPad. That's why I was wondering the reason. I don't know why I have two down vote on this question. Is it already answered? If so then please give me the link. (Last line for them who gave me down vote)

Comment: On which iPad you are testing ? and what is the size of imageview and 1x,2x and 3x image size on that imageview ?

Comment: A Non retina display iPad. My imageView size is fixed. width 44 and height 44 both for iPhone & iPad. You were saying I might be stretched the size of it in iPad and showing low uality image. But that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

In you assets folder in Xcode, right click anywhere inside the section that contains the 1x 2x 3x images. Under devices you'll see "universal", "iPhone", "iPad", etc. There you can manually drag which images are used for what devices.

[image]